# dynamically adding input on click but there's a while loop

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic

I have a while loop in a form

```
<?php
        <select>
        while($select = $sql->fetchObject())
        {
        $name=$select->name;
        $alt = $select->alt;
        echo "<option value='".$alt."'>".$name."</option>";
        }
        </select>
?>
<div id='new_name'>Add Name</div>
```

I would like to some how use jquery to dynamically add a new select option (with the same options from the while loop) on click, how would I do such a thing if theres php?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: PHP is done server-side and Javascript on client-side so please include the generated HTML rather than the PHP code.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP code is run server-side, while jQuery is JavaScript and thus run client-side, so the PHP-code will not affect jQuery. What is returned from the server is just a pure HTML  element. Therefor you can use jQuery's [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to make a copy of the select.

```
$('select').clone().appendTo('form');
```

Since you don't specify what you want to click on to add the copied select, I will just make an example of how it might look:

```
$("#my-id-to-click-on").click(function(){
    $('select').clone().appendTo('form');
});
```

**Note** Since I don't know anything about classes or ID's used on your forms and inputs, these examples use very general selectors and if you have multiple forms or multiple selects in your DOM, this will become a problem. I suggest you add ID's or classes to your forms and selects, and use those to select on instead. That way it will be more bullet proof.

You might also want to add an if-statement to make sure that the select is only copied the first time you click. If that is how you want it to behave.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am using clone actually to get my form, but the problem is, what you said ID's and Classes. Maybe I would have to do some kind of server side php coding with an array and do some imploding and exploding and have it be sent into my database.

Comment: @andrewliu I am not sure I understand how you mean. What is it that you want to store in the db?

Comment: Lets say the drop down will populate with names, and if I want to add another name, I would click "add name" (which would clone the drop down menu to add another name). Essentially I want to be able to save each name as a different row in my database, so each name will have an ID (given that the database auto increments). I guess implode and explode wouldnt be needed. But I'm just saying that because I can do endless possibilities still right?

Comment: Also, there may be a problem with .clone(), is there a possibility to remove a certain cloned element?

Answer (score 1):

You can also:

1. Generate the selects with PHP, disable and hide them, then on click enable and show.
2. Set a javascript variable with all the data (name-alt pairs) using PHP and `json_encode`, and then on click use the variable contents to generate HTML selects with javascript.